# How can I perform an OR with ScalaTest

Tags: logical-operators, scalatest

I want to logically join two ScalaTest assertions with an OR operator.

The thing is, those two assertions are checking something completely different. There are some examples using `or` in similar posts but that is not what I want to do.

Most posts are checking an OR condition **on the same variable**, i.e.

```
actual should (be (a [RuntimeException]) or be (a [Thread]))
```

But I want to join completely different things, i.e.

```
actual should (be (a [RuntimeException]) or somethingElse should be(0)
```

However, this instruction does not compile, because `or` is not a member of `assertion`. I tried several syntaxes with brackets but none of them are compiling :

```
(count should be(0)) or (isCentroid should be(true))
(count should be(0)) || (isCentroid should be(true))
```

How can I join those two assertions with OR ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Failed tests throw [`TestFailedException`](http://doc.scalatest.org/3.0.1/#org.scalatest.exceptions.TestFailedException) when using matchers, so we could wrap the assertion in `Try` and then use standard Scala logical operators like so:

```
val P1 = Try(count should be(0)).isSuccess
val P2 = Try(isCentroid should be(true)).isSuccess
assert (P1 || P2)
```

On failure we should see something like:

```
P1 was false, and P2 was false
ScalaTestFailureLocation: example.HelloSpec at (HelloSpec.scala:29)
org.scalatest.exceptions.TestFailedException: P1 was false, and P2 was false
```